# How to read SMS messages in react native?

Tags: react-native

I have a react native app that uses SMS verification and I want to have a listener for incoming SMSs to read the code automatically.

I've used [react-native-android-sms-listener](https://github.com/CentaurWarchief/react-native-android-sms-listener) but [it doesn't work](https://github.com/CentaurWarchief/react-native-android-sms-listener/issues/31) for Android 8 and above. Can anyone help?

Comment: have you found a solution?

Comment: @JasonG Not yet. but the solution is we have to port the android code to RN code. Actually now I don't need it anymore because recently Google apply some strict rules for using this permission so I have to remove it.

Comment: Did you ask for the relevant permissions? "RECEIVE_SMS"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use react-native-sms-retriever instead it supports for all versions

or else you can use react-native-get-sms-android to get all the user message in JSON and extract the data out of it.

Comment: Can you provide the example of running code as I am stuck on this  react-native-sms-retriever ?